# Read text file and search the text

Tags: c

After reading the material in the text file, if there is a corresponding name through the search, print out the name and money. However, I can only read the first line of the text file. If I want to make it read another line and find the corresponding name what can I do?

my text file has 15 lines.

```
Jane 50
Bruno 100
Kim 200
Young 150
Will 250
Jane 50
Bruno 100
Kim 200
Young 150
Will 250
Jane 50
Bruno 100
Kim 335
Young 455
Will 555
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



typedef struct user{
    char name [10];
    int money;
} userinformation;



int main()
{
    userinformation myvar[100];
    int x=0;
    char find_name[100];
    int i = 0;
    int idx = 0;
    char buffer[1001],*token;
    char* ptr;
    userinformation* userinfo;
    int cents_50=0;
    int cents_20=0;
    int cents_10=0;
    int cents_5=0;
    
    FILE * srcFile = fopen("coins.txt", "r");
    
    
    if(srcFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("fail to open file");
        return -1;
    }
    
    //file read from coins.txt
    while (!feof(srcFile))
    {
        i =0;
        fgets(buffer, 1001, srcFile);
        token = strtok(buffer, " ");
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                strcpy(myvar[idx].name, token);;
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                myvar[idx].money = atoi(token);
            }
            i++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        idx++;
    }
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i <idx; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", myvar[i].name, myvar[i].money);
    }
    fclose(srcFile);
    
    
    
    while(x != 2)
    {
        printf("1.Enter name\n");
        printf("2.Exit\n");
        scanf("%d%*c", &x);
        
        if(x ==1)
        {
            printf("Name: ");
            scanf("%s%*c", find_name);
            for(i=0; i<idx; i++)
            {
                ptr = strstr(myvar->name, find_name);
            }
            if(ptr != NULL)
            {   
                printf("Customer: \n");
                printf("%s %d\n", myvar->name, myvar->money);
                printf("Change: \n");
                //calculate 50cents;
                if(myvar->money>50) 
                {
                     myvar->money/50;
                     cents_50++;
                     printf("50 cents : %d \n", cents_50);
                }
                //calculate 20cents;
                if((myvar->money/50)<50 && myvar->money >=20)
                {
                    if((myvar->money%50/20)>=1)
                    {
                        (myvar->money%50/20);
                        cents_20++;
                        printf("20 cents : %d \n", cents_20);
                    }
                }
                //calculate 10cents;
                if((myvar->money%50%20/10)<20 && myvar->money >=10)
                {
                    if((myvar->money%50%20/10)>=1)
                    {
                        (myvar->money%50%20/10);
                        cents_10++;
                        printf("10 cents : %d \n", cents_10);
                    }
                }
                if((myvar->money%50%20%10/5)<10 && myvar->money >=5)
                {
                    if((myvar->money%50%20%10/5)>=1)
                    {
                        (myvar->money%50%20%10/5);
                        cents_5++;
                        printf("5 cents : %d \n", cents_5);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(ptr != myvar->name)
            {
                printf("Not founded\n");
            }
        }
        else if(x ==2)
            break;
    }
    
    
    return(0);
}
```

'''

Comment: Where did you get the assignment or exercise from? What is the *full* text of the assignment or exercise? Does it really tell you that you are only allowed to read one single line from the file?

Comment: It is a part of the programming assignment. Am I not allowed to ask this question?

Comment: Your question "What should I do?" is answered by "Ask the author of that assigment whether you really can only read the first line and then are expected to print information from potentially a different line." Because at leat two users here think it is simply impossible.

Comment: It's my first time using StackOverflow. I think the code I made can't read the text on the second or another line. For example, the name Ray exists, but if I search for Ray, Not found is output.

Comment: Is "you can only read the first line of the text file" part of the assignment? Or do you instead mean "But the code I wrote fails to read anything but the first line, how can I fix that?".

Comment: To begin, please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Please cleanly separet the assignment (which you might want to format as a quote, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ) from the question you ask here. "I can only read the first line of the text file." still can be misread as part of the assigment.

Comment: The code I wrote fails to read another lane.

Comment: ...the loop control  should be `while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, srcFile) != NULL)` note that I also removed the hard-coded repetiton of the buffer size. Then *print every line* read otherwise you have no way of knowing  it "only reads the first line" unless you deploy a debugger.

Comment: You can ask the question, that's okay. But please show us the original assignment text, copy-pasted in full and complete. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please don't forget the *minimal* part of your [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This seems wrong:

```
        for(i=0; i<idx; i++)
        {
            ptr = strstr(myvar->name, find_name);
        }
```

`myvar` is an array but you don't use an array index. In other words - you always use the first element of the array (i.e. `myvar[0].name`).

Besides that, I would expect that the loop should stop when `strstr` return a non-NULL value.

Did you intend to do:

```
        for(i=0; i<idx; i++)
        {
            ptr = strstr(myvar[i].name, find_name);
            if (ptr != NULL) break;
        }
```

(btw - do you really want to use `strstr`? I would expect a string compare using `strcmp` ).

The same problem, i.e. missing array index, is present in all the code that follows the above code.

BTW: The way you read from the file isn't 100% correct. See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/4386427)